# love2d just wont accept some codes

Tags: lua, love2d

Every time I use this:

```
 function love.draw()
  love.graphics.setfont(love.graphics.newfon(50))
```

I get this error:

> #### Error
>
> main.lua:2: attempt to call field `newfon` (a nil value)
>
> #### Traceback
>
> main.lua:2: in function `draw` [C]: in function `xpcall`

How can I fix it ?

Comment: 1. You're missing the `t`
2. It's case sensitive `newFont`

Answer (score 2):

Lua is case-sensitive. The correct call is

```
love.graphics.setFont(love.graphics.newFont(50))
```